# Create an object from a JSON file in python (using a classmethod)?

Tags: python, json, class-method

I wanna create a classmethod that takes a JSON (dictionary) string and creates an instance of the class it's called on.
For example, if I have a class `Person` the inherits from a class `Jsonable` with age and name:

```
class Person(Jsonable):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
class Jsonable:
    @classmethod
    def from_json(json_string):
        # do the magic here
```

and if I have a JSON string `string = "{'name': "John", 'age': 21}"` and when I say `person1 = Person.from_json(string)` I want to create person1 with name John and age 21. I also have to keep the class name in some way so that when I call for example `Car.from_json(string)` it raises a TypeError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it supposes you have a key __class in you JSON string that holds target class name

```
import json

class Jsonable(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_string):
        attributes = json.loads(json_string)
        if not isinstance(attributes, dict) or attributes.pop('__class') != cls.__name__:
            raise ValueError
        return cls(**attributes)
```

Comment: However, say I have the following method in the Jsonable: `def to_json(self, indent=4):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, indent)` which returns a dictionary with attributes as keys and values as dict values. And I want to use this same string as a parameter in the from_json method, which wouldn't have a __class key.

Comment: I'm afraid it will not contain anything like class name, so you will need to put it there by yourself.

Comment: Yeah I think I figured it out. I made it work anyways! :) Thanks!